# jQuery - Total and Subtotal with items

Tags: jquery

The HTML structure is broken out into individual `Orders` with multiple `Item`'s on each `Order`.

The problem with my code is that the `total` for each `Order` is cumulative and doesn't just add the subtotal for that instance of `Order`. How do I get the `total` for each `Order` instance instead of having the totals accumulate with each additional `Order`?

```js
$.fn.digits = function () {
  return this.each(function () {
    $(this).text(
      $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
    );
  });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
  var historyTotal = 0;
  var historyXp = 0;
  $('[data-id="history"]').each(function () {
    const item = $(this);
    var xp = 10;
    var fee = 0.15;
    var qty = item.find(".history__sold").text();
    var price = item.find(".history__cost").text();
    var subtotal = Number(qty) * Number(price);
    var xptotal = Number(qty) * Number(xp);
    var bonusXp = Number(
      item.closest("[data-id='order']").find(".bonus__xp").text()
    );
    item.find(".history__subtotal").text(subtotal.toFixed(2)).digits();
    item
      .find(".history__fee")
      .text((subtotal * (1 * fee)).toFixed(2))
      .digits();
    historyTotal += parseInt(
      item.find(".history__subtotal").text().replace(",", "")
    );
    item
      .closest("[data-id='order']")
      .find(".order__total")
      .text(((1 + fee) * historyTotal).toFixed(2))
      .digits();
    item
      .closest("[data-id='order']")
      .find(".order__fee")
      .text((fee * historyTotal).toFixed(2))
      .digits();

    //XP:
    item.find(".xp__total--history").text(xptotal).digits();
    historyXp += parseInt(
      item.find(".xp__total--history").text().replace(",", "")
    );
    item
      .closest("[data-id='order']")
      .find(".xp__total--order")
      .text(historyXp)
      .digits();
  });
  $("[data-id='order']").each(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    const item = $(this).find(".xp__total--order");
    sum += parseInt(item.text().replace(",", ""));
    $("#total_xp").text(sum).digits();
  });
  $("[data-id='order']").each(function () {
    var sum = 0;
    const item = $(this).find(".order__total");
    sum += parseInt(item.text().replace(",", ""));
    $("#total_grand").text(sum).digits();
  });
});
```

```css
span {
  margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
.header {
  padding: 0.9rem 2.3rem;
  border: 3px solid blue;
}
.header__label {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
}
.header__label span {
  margin-left: auto;
}
.history__name {
  background: #fafafa;
  padding: 0.9rem 0;
}
[data-id="order"] {
  padding: 0.9rem 2.3rem;
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 2.3rem 0
}
[data-id="history"] {
  margin: 1.3rem 0.9rem;
  padding: 0.9rem;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
[data-id="history"] > * {
  margin: 0.3rem 0;
}
.history__subtotal {
  border: 1px solid;
}
.order__header {
  background: #ececec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
  <div class="header__label">Grandtotal:<span id="total_grand">0</span> </div>
  <div class="header__label">XP:<span id="total_xp">0</span></div>
</div>
<div data-id='order'>
  <div class="order__header">
    <div class="header__label">Order Total: <span class="order__total">000</span></div>
    <div class="header__label">Order Fee: <span class="order__fee">000</span></div>
    <div class="header__label">Order XP: <span class="xp__total--order">000</span></div>
  </div>
  <div data-id='history'>
    <div class="history__name">Item 1 (10xp)</div>
    <div><span class="history__sold">25</span>Sold</div>
    <div><span class="history__cost">10</span>Cost</div>
    <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
    <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
    <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
  </div>
  <div data-id='history'>
    <div class="history__name">Item 2 (10xp)</div>
    <div><span class="history__sold">10</span>Sold</div>
    <div><span class="history__cost">50</span>Cost</div>
    <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
    <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
    <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div data-id='order'>
  <div class="order__header">
    <div class="header__label">Order Total: <span class="order__total">000</span></div>
    <div class="header__label">Order Fee: <span class="order__fee">000</span></div>
    <div class="header__label">Order XP: <span class="xp__total--order">000</span></div>
  </div>
  <div data-id='history'>
    <div class="history__name">Item 1 (10xp)</div>
    <div><span class="history__sold">25</span>Sold</div>
    <div><span class="history__cost">10</span>Cost</div>
    <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
    <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
    <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
  </div>
  <div data-id='history'>
    <div class="history__name">Item 2 (10xp)</div>
    <div><span class="history__sold">10</span>Sold</div>
    <div><span class="history__cost">50</span>Cost</div>
    <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
    <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
    <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to run a nested .each loop  `$('[data-id="order"]').each ( ..... $('[data-id="history"]').each(.....).....  )`

Comment: Are you able to provide a working snippet as an answer?

Comment: I have added the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run a nested .each loop if you want to show individual subtotals, as shown here....

```js
 $.fn.digits = function () {
            return this.each(function () {
                $(this).text(
                    $(this)
                        .text()
                        .replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,")
                );
            });
        };
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('[data-id="order"]').each(function () {
                var historyTotal = 0;
                var historyXp = 0;

                $(this).find('[data-id="history"]').each(function () {

                    const item = $(this);
                    var xp = 10;
                    var fee = 0.15;
                    var qty = item.find(".history__sold").text();
                    var price = item.find(".history__cost").text();
                    var subtotal = Number(qty) * Number(price);
                    var xptotal = Number(qty) * Number(xp);

                    var bonusXp = Number(
                        item.closest("[data-id='order']").find(".bonus__xp").text()
                    );

                    item.find(".history__subtotal").text(subtotal.toFixed(2)).digits();

                    item.find(".history__fee").text((subtotal * fee).toFixed(2)).digits();

                    historyTotal += subtotal;

                    /*
                    historyTotal += parseInt(
                        item.find(".history__subtotal").text().replace(",", "")
                    );*/

                    item.closest("[data-id='order']").find(".order__total").text(((1 + fee) * historyTotal).toFixed(2)).digits();

                    item.closest("[data-id='order']").find(".order__fee").text((fee * historyTotal).toFixed(2)).digits();

                    //XP:
                    item.find(".xp__total--history").text(xptotal).digits();

                    historyXp += parseInt(item.find(".xp__total--history").text().replace(",", ""));

                    item.closest("[data-id='order']").find(".xp__total--order").text(historyXp).digits();
                });




            });



            var sum = 0;
            $("[data-id='order']").each(function () {
                const item = $(this).find(".xp__total--order");
                sum += parseInt(item.text().replace(",", ""));
                $("#total_xp").text(sum).digits();
            });

            var sum = 0;
            $("[data-id='order']").each(function () {
                const item = $(this).find(".order__total");
                sum += parseFloat(item.text().replace(",", ""));
            });

            $("#total_grand").text(sum.toFixed(2)).digits();

        });
```

```css
        span {
            margin-right: 0.3rem;
        }

        .header {
            padding: 0.9rem 2.3rem;
            border: 3px solid blue;
        }

        .header__label {
            display: flex;
            width: 200px;
        }

            .header__label span {
                margin-left: auto;
            }

        .history__name {
            background: #fafafa;
            padding: 0.9rem 0;
        }

        [data-id="order"] {
            padding: 0.9rem 2.3rem;
            border: 2px solid;
            margin: 2.3rem 0
        }

        [data-id="history"] {
            margin: 1.3rem 0.9rem;
            padding: 0.9rem;
            border: 2px solid green;
        }

            [data-id="history"] > * {
                margin: 0.3rem 0;
            }

        .history__subtotal {
            border: 1px solid;
        }

        .order__header {
            background: #ececec;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">
        <div class="header__label">Grandtotal:<span id="total_grand">0</span> </div>
        <div class="header__label">XP:<span id="total_xp">0</span></div>
    </div>
    <div data-id='order'>
        <div class="order__header">
            <div class="header__label">Order Total: <span class="order__total">000</span></div>
            <div class="header__label">Order Fee: <span class="order__fee">000</span></div>
            <div class="header__label">Order XP: <span class="xp__total--order">000</span></div>
        </div>
        <div data-id='history'>
            <div class="history__name">Item 1 (10xp)</div>
            <div><span class="history__sold">25</span>Sold</div>
            <div><span class="history__cost">10</span>Cost</div>
            <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
            <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
            <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
        </div>
        <div data-id='history'>
            <div class="history__name">Item 2 (10xp)</div>
            <div><span class="history__sold">10</span>Sold</div>
            <div><span class="history__cost">50</span>Cost</div>
            <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
            <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
            <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-id='order'>
        <div class="order__header">
            <div class="header__label">Order Total: <span class="order__total">000</span></div>
            <div class="header__label">Order Fee: <span class="order__fee">000</span></div>
            <div class="header__label">Order XP: <span class="xp__total--order">000</span></div>
        </div>
        <div data-id='history'>
            <div class="history__name">Item 1 (10xp)</div>
            <div><span class="history__sold">25</span>Sold</div>
            <div><span class="history__cost">10</span>Cost</div>
            <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
            <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
            <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
        </div>
        <div data-id='history'>
            <div class="history__name">Item 2 (10xp)</div>
            <div><span class="history__sold">10</span>Sold</div>
            <div><span class="history__cost">50</span>Cost</div>
            <div><span class="history__subtotal">000</span>Subtotal</div>
            <div>Fee:<span class="history__fee">0</span></div>
            <div><span class="xp__total--history">000</span>XP</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```